# How to Add/Update/Delete a value in Redis cache

Tags: c#, redis, .net-core

I am just new to distributed cache, I have the following code below, which stores the list value of users from a database table in the cache if it does not exist.

```
var cacheKey ="samplekey";

var userListdata = //contains list of users from a db table

var data = _distributedCache.GetString(cacheKey);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
{
    var tModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<user>>(data);
    return new CommandActionResult<List<user>>(tModel, CommandActionStatus.NothingModified);
}
else
{
    var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userListdata);
    _distributedCache.SetString(cacheKey, jsonData);
    return new CommandActionResult<List<user>>(null, CommandActionStatus.NothingModified);
}
```

in a case where I have a new user to add/remove/update from the table, how do I Add/update/Delete the **samplekey** cache key?

Comment: What cache are you using ? Redis ?

Comment: @NgôHùngPhúc yes redis

Answer (score 1):

To Update a item in list in .netcore for distributed caching use **ListSetByIndexAsync** function provided in **Distributed cache** library and can be accessed through **IDistributedCache** interface

```cs
  await _cache.ListSetByIndexAsync(key,index, redisValue);
```

- key is cache key
- index is index position to update
- redisValue is the item to be updated in the list

To access the index use IndexOf function.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the approache. Save each user in the userListdata like a unique keyValuePair in redis cache. Then you can use this for insert/update/delete.

```
// add the users to azure redis cache
foreach (var user in userListdata)
{
    _distributedCache.StringSet(user.Id, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user));
}
// update/delete your records
var data = _distributedCache.GetString(cacheKey);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data)){
    _distributedCache.KeyDelete(cacheKey);
    _distributedCache.StringSet(cacheKey, newValues);
}
// else insert a new one...
```